# Spring data REST PreInsertEventListener not firing?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data

i noticed that the hibernate `PreInsertEventListener` is not executed, when data is persisted with spring data REST. Any reason for that except a bug?
The listener is executed, when data is persisted through `@Controller -> @Service -> @Repository`.

Comment: can put some code here to understand that?

Comment: is it your case? [insert and update action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30064400/7214142)

Comment: thx, i switched to org.hibernate.Interceptor which is called